# Python selenium sending keys into textarea

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Python 3.4.4 to access a website (https://readability-score.com/) that has a textarea, which dynamically updates when new values are added.

I'm trying to input a string into that textarea box but it isn't working for me.

Here's the code that I'm trying:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
URL = "https://readability-score.com/"

text = "Hello hello hello, this is a test"

driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("text_to_score").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("text_to_score").send_keys(text)
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/textarea").clear()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/textarea").send_keys(text)
```

The problem is that the selenium driver can not find the textarea to send the keys into. I think it's able to clear it (because I can literally see the text being cleared when you enter the page) but no text can be enter. Would anyone have an idea about this? I followed the online guide but I felt like I've tried all options that were listed (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). Thanks.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: Oh yeah, good point. I'll edit this but the error is that the selenium driver can't send text into the textarea.

Comment: Hmm, put some delay after send_keys statement so you can actually see whether your text is entering into the textarea or not ?

Comment: Still nothing for me. Even with a delay

Comment: Did clear statement clears the default text ? If yes then try removing that statement and use only send_keys() statement

Comment: It does clear the text but still does not enter it in..hmm

Comment: Let's try this. after clear statement perform a click on textarea e.g
driver.find_element_by_id("text_to_score").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("text_to_score").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("text_to_score").send_keys(text)

Comment: No but it seems like the issue wasn't with selenium but with the text, actually. So what we've been doing was correct. I lied a bit about the text input, that string was just a simple typed out example because I thought all strings were treated the same but the real string that I used has about 1000+ words and is imported through a external text file by using the open command with read(). That seems to be the problem but I'm trying to find how I can input that entire text into this area.

Comment: Let me play around with this but thank you so much for your help (and everyone else), Hassan.

Answer (score 7):

[You can explicitly wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) until the textarea appear.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


...


url = "https://readability-score.com/"
text = "Hello hello hello, this is a test"

driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "text_to_score"))
)  # Wait until the `text_to_score` element appear (up to 5 seconds)
driver.find_element_by_id("text_to_score").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id('text_to_score').send_keys(text)
```

Comment: The problem isn't that the driver can't find the element (because I can see it clearing the default text) but it just can't enter the text

Comment: @user1342086, It's weird. It works perfect for me (both for Firefox, Chrome). BTW, which versino of selenium package do you use? I'm using 2.53.1.

Comment: Yes, you may be correct. I lied about the sample text above and I'm actually importing a text file in using the open and .read() methods to bring in text. So this is a correct solution (I didn't try this but it looks fine).

Comment: Can you explain how we can press enter to send our text?

Comment: @hamed_baziyad, See [this question]( See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312033/enter-key-press-using-selenium-webdriver-with-python). If that does not help you to solve our problem, please post a separate question (not comment) with url (or html) you're dealing with.

Comment: @falsetru  It didn't help me

Comment: @user7621299  
.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) 

will need to import 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Answer (score 3):

the "send_keys" function only TYPES out the string you input, but does not "send" the keys, as counterintuitive as that may seem. The proper way to submit the textarea would be with a simple

```
driver.find_element_by_id("text_to_score").submit()
```

OR

```
textarea = driver.find_element_by_id("text_to_score")
textarea.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me

```
textarea = driver.find_element(By.ID, "text_to_score")
textarea.click()
textarea = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "text_to_score")
textarea.send_keys('your text')
```

you can use the different elements for input text to one field text area.