# ENTER key press using Selenium WebDriver with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I simulate the ENTER key press using selenium python bindings? I have tried the following block but it is not working.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/xxxxx").send_keys('keys.ENTER')
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_name("element_name").send_keys("ENTER")
```

Comment: Actually, even though it the same question in essence, the problem here is that very often a webpage will not accept `.send_keys(ENTER)` or anything like that, and instead the unicodes have to be used. Please do not remove this question from SO, as the other question does not mention the unicodes at all.

Answer (score 33):

Use these codes from the API docs: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys

Eg. ENTER would be `.send_keys(u'\ue007')`

Answer (score 1):

Try `keys.ENTER`, not as a string (take the single quotes off).

Comment: Hi,Thank you for this answer. Actually the webpage donot accept any keyboard inputs, other than ARROW KEYS and ENTER button. control is not navigating to the particular button on which i want to press ENTER. I am using this block of code.....        driver.find_element_by_name("element_name").send_keys('ArrowLeft')
        driver.find_element_by_name("element_name").send_keys('ENTER')
 it fails every time.