# How do I send text into a textarea through Selenium and Python as per the HTML:(

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to click and send text within a textbox but not able to find the element.
This is the html I want to click and send text

```html
<div class="text_write_g comment_write">
        <div class="inner_text_write">
            <div class="box_textarea">
                <textarea placeholder="add coment." maxlength="600" style="height: 86px;"></textarea>
                                
            </div>
            <div class="wrap_menu">
                <div class="area_l">
                    <button class="btn_g_ico btn_item image_upload_button" data-image-url="" data-image-name="" data-image-size="" id="attach_uploader0"><span class="ico_bbs ico_photo">image_upload</span></button>
                    <div class="keyboard_wrapper">
                        <div id="buttonLayer0">
                            <button id="keyboardBtn0" class="keyboard_btn btn_g_ico btn_item"><span class="ico_bbs ico_emoticon">imoticon</span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="area_r">
                    <span class="num_text"><span class="sr_only">text_number</span><span class="num_count empty">0</span>/<span class="sr_only">total_text_number</span>600</span>
                    <button class="btn_g_ico btn_item secret_button " data-is-hidden=""><span class="ico_bbs ico_lock_state">secret_reply</span></button>
                    <div class="btn_group">
                        <button class="btn_g full_type1 confirm_button" style="font-size: 13px;">confirm</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried around 100ways but not work it...;(
I googled it also searched in stackoverflow
please please help this newbie
I struggled 3days already...:(

Comment: You might need to wait until the elements are loaded completely.. This could help you to make selenium to wait until the element is available.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614118/python-selenium-sending-keys-into-textarea

Comment: I tried this already also time.sleep(10) :(

Comment: TimeoutException error is pop out......How could I do ;( super sad